# Exception when generating Expression.Assign to set decimal? from decimal

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, expression-trees

I ran into an interesting issue when building Expressions. I had some basic type coercion checks going to ensure minimal casting was done, however, I ran into an issue I didn't expect.

When I am trying to generate a `BinaryExpression` using `Expression.Assign` and I am going from `decimal` to `decimal?` I receive the exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Nullable'1[System.Decimal]

Can someone explain this? Considering the following evaluates to true:

```
typeof(decimal?).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(decimal))
```

The expected assignment should be equal to the statements below:

```
decimal? x = null;
decimal y = 10;
x = y;
```

Code in question:

```
private Expression BuildMapExpressionForValueMap(MemberInfo destinationProperty, MemberInfo sourceProperty)
{
    Expression assignmentExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(_source, sourceProperty.Name);
    Type destinationType = destinationProperty.GetUnderlyingType();

    if (!destinationType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.GetUnderlyingType()))
    {
        assignmentExpression = BuildCastExpression(assignmentExpression, destinationType);
    }

    var expression = Expression.Assign(Expression.PropertyOrField(_destination, destinationProperty.Name)
                                     , assignmentExpression);


    return expression;
}
```

Comment: The C# compiler automatically puts in an `Expression.Convert(y, typeof(Decimal?))` when creating an `Expression` tree from a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are implicit conversions from the non-nullable value types to the corresponding nullable type. The expressions you generate must be explicit. The same reason why you can't generate an expression assigning an Int32 to a variable of type Int64. The compiler generates the conversion calls explicitly so you don't have to. Try it and you'll see.

You must add the conversion.

```
var param = Expression.Variable(typeof(decimal?));
var value = Expression.Constant(20m, typeof(decimal));
var expr = Expression.Assign(param,
    //value // fails
    Expression.Convert(value, param.Type)
);
```

Comment: That makes sense, didn't think about it. I ended up implementing a two way check (i.e A->B, B->A).  Is there a reason why trees wouldn't implement the same explicit call?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. The expression trees try to cover all the possible expression types that you will need (though it certainly isn't exhaustive). It doesn't implement some of the compiler magic that is done for you unfortunately (no generators, async/await methods, implicit conversions, etc.).

Comment: No need to apologize, it was a rather vague question, but you did answer it. I was mainly curious why some of the compiler magic was missing, if it's because of technical limitations or it's just a feature that wasn't implement by design?

Comment: @SamirBanjanovic: Expression trees don't go through the C# compiler; they are language independent

Comment: @BenVoigt good point. Complete oversight on my end that it's language agnostic

Answer (score 1):

When you write a regular c# code, compiler do implicit conversions to you for free. But when you dealing with a `Linq.Expressions` you should explicitly define each type cast.

Check this code, it is assign an `y` to `x` and then print it to console:

```
var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(decimal?), "x");
var paramY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(decimal), "y");

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<decimal?, decimal>>(
    Expression.Block(
        Expression.Assign(paramX, Expression.Convert(paramY, typeof(decimal?)))
        , Expression.Call(typeof(Console), "WriteLine", new Type[0],
            Expression.Convert(paramX, typeof(decimal)))
        ),
    paramX, paramY);

lambda.Compile().Invoke(null, 10);
```

You can find a demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JYsfAP)